# Understanding the definition of a limit using neighborhoods in $R^1$ (Rudin)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

[image]

1- Why did he require $V \cap E$ to be nonempty? 
(If $x$ is in $E$ or $x$ is a limit point of $E$, then $V \cap E$ is always nonempty.

2- Why didn't he require $x$ to be a limit point of $E$? What if $x$ were isolated?
(In the general definition of a limit on metric spaces, $x$ has to be a limit point of $E$)

Comment: Doesn't the extended real number system include $\pm \infty$?

Comment: @JonathanBrown Yes, but then what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the empty set: any predicate of $z$ that follows "$\forall z \in \varnothing$" makes the proposition true. Suppose you want to take the limit of $f$ as $t\to x$, but $x$ is not an accumulation point of $E$. Then there exists at least a neighborhood of $x$ that does not intersect $E$, which means that the condition
$$\exists A\ \mathrm{s.t.}\quad \forall U \in \mathcal U(A) \quad \exists V \in \mathcal U(x)\ \mathrm{s.t.} \quad  \forall t \in V \cap E \setminus \{x\} \qquad f(t) \in U $$
would always be true because *there are no* $t$'s in $V \cap E \setminus \{x\}$. That would imply that *any* $A$ would work and would render the definition of limit quite useless.

So that is why he requires $V \cap E \neq \varnothing$.

Comment: But if x is not an accumulation point of $E$, then $x$ must be in $E$. Hence $V∩E=x$, right? I mean he should have required a stronger condition; like $V∩E$ must contain points other than $x$. $$$$
Does $V∩E \setminus \{x\}$ mean the points in the intersection of the neighborhood $V$ and the set $E$ other than the point $x$? $$$$
What do $\mathcal U(A)$ and $\mathcal U(x)$ refer to?